# Batch File: List all files not beginning with "SP"

Tags: regex, file, batch-file, cmd, dos

I have a DOS batch file that performs an action for files beginning with text "SP", as follows:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ( 'DIR SP*.sql /s /b' ) DO ECHO .compile_file = "%%A" >> output.txt
```

The key bit here is obviously:

```
DIR SP*.sql /s /b
```

I need to do a similar thing before the "FOR" line above, but for all other files not starting with SP*.sql

Something like:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ( 'DIR [^SP]*.sql /s /b' ) DO ECHO .run_file = "%%A" >> output.txt
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ( 'DIR SP*.sql /s /b' ) DO ECHO .compile_file = "%%A" >> output.txt
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?
Can I use regex for this sort of thing?

The batch file will run under CMD in Windows XP.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In batch, usually you can use `findstr` with `/V` to negate regex , eg

```
.... | findstr /V "^SPL"
```

try passing the filename to `findstr` and see how it goes

```
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
```